# Why don't ATMs give you cash before your card?

Tags: conventions, physical, checkout, banking

I live in Australia, so this might not apply worldwide, but here, when withdrawing money, the ATM will give me back my bank card, then several seconds later the cash comes out.

This typically leads to forgetting to take the cash, especially when my mind is elsewhere.

Given that I put the card into the machine, aren't I less likely to forget to wait for it? Wouldn't it make more sense to wait until I take the cash, then output my card?

Comment: what if you take cash first and forget to take your card? is that ok?

Comment: Well, the cash is typically more valuable to me than the card. But my original thought was that the psychology in inserting the card would mean you remember to take it out again so it wouldn't matter if it came second in the process.

Comment: I was told that the first ATM versions *did* give you cash before your card, but they had to redesign the solution because **Most users considered "receiving cash" as "my task is completed" and thus they left the ATM immediately (without the card) when they had accomplished what they came for...**

Comment: In the US, cards seldom 'go in' - you insert and take it out, enter pin and perform transaction. So card is back in the wallet and money is in the pocket :)

Comment: If you leave your card behind (especially if it's a credit card), the impact is likely to be very high on you: your card could be used fraudulently (particularly online) and you would need to call your bank/card provider and get it cancelled. If you leave money behind, you're probably out less money overall, and you're definitely less likely to need to call your bank. Nonetheless, an insert-and-remove style card reader as most new ATMS use seems to be preferable in every way.

Comment: You can also provide better user experience, because of fact that cash can be recollected by the ATM if you forget to take it (also your account balance can be corrected). Storing cards is much more painful to a user.

Comment: Some of the ATM's in India allows the user to swipe the card and then let the user do the transaction. This way they dont forget to take the cash as well as card

Comment: In France, the ATM will get the money back if you didn't pull the notes in a delay of 30–60 seconds. In this case, you might be not charged at all.

Comment: I'm protecting this question as we're getting far too many *"In {insert country name} we do it like this..."* answers which don't help anyone. Please **cite actual research or evidence** when answering this question. Anecdotes are not answers.

Comment: In Belgium, the money comes out first, which causes people to forget to pick their card back...

Comment: I work for a company that produces ATMs in a number of countries; everything is configurable by the individual bank, but out of the box our products do retract cash fairly quickly if not taken. They also retract and swallow cards if not taken (assuming it takes a card into the machine in the first place, as opposed to a Dip reader) as well as receipts. It appears to be less about "what will get stolen" and more about "what will cost more time and effort to replace", but I have no access to the research we did (not my department)

Comment: @PhD That's a more recent development.  About 4-5 years ago, when I started using my debit card regularly, ATMs in the US usually did hold your card until after you received your cash.

Comment: @KitGrose Also, you're more likely to notice having left your money behind sooner (since you withdrew money with presumably the intent to spend it immediately), rather than the next time you need to use your card and don't have it.

Comment: In the US, Bank of America ATMs recently (in the past year or so?) started returning the card to you before asking for your PIN. I always inferred that too many people left their cards behind after receiving their cash.

Comment: In the US people swipe their card in the machine, so it never goes somewhere else than in the user's hand or in his wallet. I think this is the best approach.

Comment: In Mexico, it's the other way around! :-) I live in Australia and I like it more here like this!

Comment: @Yamikuronue once a got distracted at an ATM and the thing retracted the cash as well as the card.  It was a saturday night and i had to wait til monday to get the card back in the bank the ATM was set afront. I guess the perfect solution would be that the machine retracts the card only when it senses (by distance sensor) a customer walking away (maybe after audibly calling them back).

Comment: @kioopi In the case of a sensor malfunction, though, it's better to have the customer mildly inconvenienced by a retract than have someone steal their cash. If they retract the money, it generally cancels the withdrawl

Comment: @Yamikuronue True, it's always trade-offs. It's probably important to keep the ATM low maintenance and having fewer parts that could malfunction goes a long way.

Comment: @JørnE.Angeltveit, 100 upvotes calls for [citation needed](http://xkcd.com/285).

Answer (score 74, accepted):

I found an article that explains this.

Apparently, in Argentina, ATMs give cash before the card, resulting in a large amount of people leaving their cards behind. See http://uxmovement.com/thinking/preventing-user-errors-in-automated-teller-machines/ - unfortunately there are no references cited so I'm unsure how true this is.

To me, however, it would make more sense if your card was returned to you before entering your PIN.

As Jørn explains, it comes down to when the user considers the task completed. You're at the ATM to get cash, you're more likely to remain at the ATM until you receive your cash.

Comment: Nice explanation.  The key point in the article is the user's mental model of *task completion* as I commented above.

Comment: Behind this 100%, here where I live in the States, the two ATMs I go to (only a few miles apart) actually do them different ways, and I constantly fear forgetting my card because I never remember which one gives it back to me first.

Comment: I believe that with modern chip cards, you could not get the card back before entering the PIN. It needs the card to verify it.

Comment: The same applies to me in the United Kingdom. In the 1990s ATMs used to give the cash before the card, but people kept leaving the card in  the machine after taking their money. I don't know when the change happened, but nowadays it gives the card first, and people no longer leave their card behind.

Comment: +1 this. Infact I remember a case when someone posted on a forum that his wife went to get some cash, took the cash and forgot about the card. Went back to get the card and it was gone.

Comment: The main ATMs I use here take your card and then immediately gives it back to you and prompts you for PIN, and what you want to do.

Comment: @earlz out of interest What kind of feedback do you receive to say the transaction is complete? in UK you get card then cash which I feels acts well as this feedback. Using yours I might feel a bit anxious the person behind me might be able to access my account.

Comment: I work for the leading ATM supplier, so I can tell you exactly what happens. The application on the ATM can be configured in any way you want. It is particular banks decision on how the transaction flow should look like. Different banks have different wishes. But the general idea is. You want to get both the card and the money. People are generally waiting for the money (because that is why they approached the ATM in the first place), so they will get the card first (so they will not forget to take it).

Comment: I'm from Mexico and here you receive cash before card.

Comment: @Bart van Heukelom - good point about chip cards. In Australia, we have ATMs that don't retain your card; they must check the PIN against the bank regardless.

Comment: ATMs seize your card if you enter an incorrect pin many times.  They could not do this if they give back the card before you enter pin ..

Comment: @wim: What good does retaining the card do?  In the cases where the bank would have the machine retain the card, it should also invalidate the associated account number in case someone has a copy of the card.  If the bank does that, someone with a card that has that now-invalid number isn't going to be able to do anything with it.  Failure to retain the card would forfeit any chance the bank would have to do anything useful with it, but I'm not sure what the bank could usefully do with it anyhow.  Perhaps tally how many seized cards are real and how many are "white plastic" copies, but...

Comment: ...even if the bank could tally that information, what would it gain by doing so?

Comment: @Tass, Sure, if money came out first you forget the card and if card came out first you forget the money. But you have not answered, "So how do we fix this problem from a usability perspective?"

Comment: @Pacerier, others suggested the card not be retained by the ATM at all. I like this idea - you'd walk up to the machine, dip your card in (like paying at a checkout) enter your PIN, etc. and get your money. Your card will already be back in your possession before the cash comes out.

Comment: @Tass I suggest giving the card back before the pin would be a security risk.  A low percentage of users will put their card in and then change their mind and simply walk away with their card.  Once the card is taken, you don't want to allow the next person in the queue to steal cash.  There used to be ATMs in the UK which immediately gave you the card back but then had to ask for it a second time before actually dispensing cash.

Answer (score 27):

Unfortunately there aren't many real references to help answer this question. [UXMovement has an article](http://uxmovement.com/thinking/preventing-user-errors-in-automated-teller-machines/) which Tass references in their answer, which makes some good points about the task flow of using ATMs. In summary:

- Users follow the tasks in sequence, but **regard the task as completed once they have achieved their goal**. Subsidiary steps are easy to abandon at this point.
- There are two ways to arrange the task flow: card then cash, or cash then card.
- The **typical user goal at an ATM is to withdraw money**, meaning that receiving cash marks the end of their task.
- When the card is dispensed first, users have not completed their goal so remain in the task flow.
- When cash is dispensed first, **users mentally abandon the task flow** before receiving their card, meaning that they are more prone to forgetting it.

Another resource is [Nudge blog's article](http://nudges.org/2011/03/15/rethinking-the-choice-architecture-of-atm-machines/) which argues along similar lines, further highlighting the issue of achieving objectives and abandoning the task flow due to a feeling of "mission accomplished".

Comment: There is a youtube collection detailling observations in this area www.youtube.com/watch?v=uUR_AGltYoY . On a side note, ATMs can lock a card/pin if the pin is entered incorrectly 3 times. This could explain why they sometimes don't give your card back immediately (along with other security sequences). Otherwise a greater separation between card and cash return phases might have helped. Though I've found no evidence to support that theory.

Comment: There's quite a lot of psychological research (which I'm going to have to look up) which covers this whole field of task management in problem solving (which we do all the time).  Some problem solving tasks can get quite complex !:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi

Answer (score 21):

This exact questioned is actually answered!  This questioned is an example of a **Forcing Function** described in the book  [**Design of Everyday Things**](http://books.google.com/books?id=w8pM72p_dpoC&pg=PA137&lpg=PA137&dq=the%20design%20of%20everyday%20things%20forcing%20function&source=bl&ots=WpVhycr3RH&sig=MzaaIBjPgCfeaDipIGR9xNYfjlg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5acGUMiCJYGQ6wH97eTMCA&sqi=2&ved=0CFUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=the%20design%20of%20everyday%20things%20forcing%20function&f=false/%22Design%20of%20Everyday%20Things%22) by **Donald A. Norman**

*Forcing Function Defined*

> Forcing functions are a form of physical constraint: situations in
>   which the actions are constrained so that failure at one stage
>   prevents the next step from happening. Starting a car
>   has a forcing function associated with it—you must put the ignition
>   key into the ignition switch. Some time ago, the button that activated
>   the starter motor was separate from the ignition key, so that it was
>   possible to attempt to start the car without the keys; the error was
>   made frequently. In most modern automobiles, the starter switch is
>   activated by turning the key—an effective forcing function that makes
>   you use the key to do the operation.
>
> Using a bank or credit card to withdraw money from an **automatic
>   teller machine**, then walking off without the card. This was a
>   frequent enough error that many machines now have a forcing function:
>   you must remove the card before the money will be delivered. **Of
>   course, you then can walk off without your money, but this is less
>   likely than forgetting the card because money is the goal of using the
>   machine.** The possibility exists so the forcing function isn’t
>   perfect.

*ATM as a Forcing Function*

> Forcing functions are the extreme case of strong constraints that make
>   it easy to discover erroneous behavior. Not every situation allows
>   such strong constraints to operate, but the general principle can be
>   extended to a wide variety of situations. In the field of safety
>   engineering, forcing functions show up under other names, in
>   particular as specialized methods for the prevention of accidents.
>   Three such methods are interlocks, lockins, and lockouts.

The Three Types of Forcing Functions

> An **interlock** forces operations to take place in proper sequence
>   (figure 5.4). Microwave ovens and television sets use interlocks as
>   forcing functions to prevent people from opening the door of the oven
>   or taking off the back of the television set without first turning off
>   the electric power: the interlock disconnects the power the instant
>   the door is opened or the back removed. The pin on a fire extinguisher
>   or hand grenade and the safety on a rifle are other examples of
>   interlocks; these forcing functions prevent the accidental use of the
>   devices.
>
> A **lockin** keeps an operation active, preventing someone from
>   prematurely stopping it. The sad stories of those who turn off word
>   processors without first saving their work could be avoided with the
>   use of a lockin. Suppose the on-off switch were a “soft” switch, not
>   really disconnecting the power, but sending a signal to the program to
>   quit, checking that all files had been saved, and then, after all the
>   appropriate housekeeping operations had been completed, turning off
>   the power. (Of course, a normal power switch should also exist as an
>   override for special situations or for when a software problem causes
>   the soft switch to fail.)
>
> A **lockout** device is one that prevents someone from entering a place
>   that is dangerous, or prevents an event from occurring. A good example
>   of a lockout occurs in stairways of public buildings, at least in the
>   United States (figure 5.5). In cases of fire, people have a tendency
>   to flee in panic, down the stairs, down, down, down, past the ground
>   floor and into the basement, where they are trapped. The solution
>   (required by the fire laws) is not to allow simple passage from the
>   ground floor to the basement.

**The ATM is a Lockout Forcing Function.**

Comment: Big points for referencing Don Norman's excellent book. Regarding ATMs, most of the newer ones I've seen ask the user to dip the card into the reader and quickly remove it. In this flow, the card never leaves the user's hand -- which is a good way to make sure the user doesn't forget the card. Two more examples of lockouts from autos: diesel gas nozzles are bigger than regular petrol nozzles, preventing fill-ups with wrong fuel; and manual transmissions prevent ignition if the clutch pedal is not pushed to the floor, preventing starting in gear.

Comment: @RobC As mentioned above, this solution is not possible with the "European type" cards and ATMs.

Answer (score 14):

Well its a human behavior that we never forget to take the money :).

When we step into an ATM our primary task is to take the cash. So we are always in a mindset where we are trying to understand how much do I want to take out and what denomination will I get. In this phase we are all thinking about the CASH. The Card is just a medium to authenticate the transaction.

Now on the other hand, losing a card can be more dangerous than losing cash.

There is plenty of research to support the theory when we have only one task to complete we have very minimum chances to forget that. As such when we go to ATM our primary task is to take the cash and hence we generally don't forget that. That is the reason, we get CASH at last and we get the card back before we take the cash and leave the ATM booth.

Comment: If you're going to include comments such as *"There is plenty of research to support the theory"* in an answer then it's advisable to at least include some links to such studies.

Comment: Since you put a smiley after "its a human behavior that we never forget to take the money", you probably mean that, in fact, we sometime do forget the money. That makes the rest of the answer a bit weak.

Comment: Old joke: "In the delivery room, they never wonder who the *mother* is."

Answer (score 6):

Most likely because it costs something to a bank if you forget your card. While it costs them nothing if you forget your cash. This feature is not designed for users but for banks.

The excuse that "many people forget their cards" is not credible - just as many people probably forget their cash, except you'll never hear about it since there's nowhere they can go to complain.

**Edit:**

To anwer some of the comments - if you lose your card, [the bank is reponsible for any illegal transaction](http://web.archive.org/web/20150401034017/http://www.usa.gov/topics/money/banking/atm-debit.shtml):

- If you report a debit card missing before it is used, you are not responsible for any unauthorized withdrawals.
- Your liability is limited to $50 if you report the loss within two business days after you realize your debit card is missing and to $500 if you report the loss after two but before 60 days.

This is why, if you lose your card, it's a much bigger problem **for the bank, not for you**. If you forget $100 at the ATM, it's lost and you have no option. If you lose your card, at most you will lose $50, or nothing if you report it immediately.

Comment: *Why* is that not credible?

Comment: This answer is very speculative. Do you have any resources or evidence to back up your claim?

Comment: I doubt banks would admit they changed ATMs for their own benefit, and to the detriment of their customers. They will most likely come up with excuses like, indeed, "many people forget their cards". From a customer perspective it's obvious that forgetting the cash can be much more costly than forgetting a card.

Comment: @Laurent it is not obvious that it's more costly to forget cash than the card. If you leave $10 behind that may be preferable than leaving a card behind that could be used by someone to get $10,000.

Comment: @JonW, if you lose $10,000 just because you forgot your card, your bank must have some serious security issues. In mine, you'll need the PIN to pay in a shop, or the 3D-Secure password if you order online. Even if you have this they won't allow withdrawing that kind of amount without checking your identity first.

Comment: Yes, the chances are slim but do exist (card cloning etc), but the chance of someone getting access to your account by using the $10 you left in the machine are non-existant.

Comment: Losing a card can be much much more costly than losing a few hundred dollars cash that you forgot to grab.

Comment: @Chad, it depends where you are from - in the US and Europe, most banks will refund your account if you lose your card and it's used illegally. See updated post.

Comment: I like these USA rules, in US dollars, stated as absolute rules. 
The United States of America are the world, of course.

Comment: @NicolasBarbulesco, I'm not from the US and I've never been there but it's a useful reference for the sake of discussion (and because most users are from there). The rules are similar in other countries I lived in.

Comment: @JonW, Because if you lose $10,000 due to someone guessing your pin and having access to your card, **the bank needs return you the $10,000** and suffer the loss themselves. Typically they would have a chance of getting the money back if the criminal is caught (ATMs have 24/7 cameras). You see, you are actually supporting his answer.

Comment: @this.law_, Link broken, please update. http://web.archive.org/web/20150401034017/http://www.usa.gov/topics/money/banking/atm-debit.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Because the "mental model" of the user is that receiving the cash is the end of the transaction. *That's* the walkaway point; risking leaving the card in the ATM. Banks and users therefore had to spend much time, effort, and costs in replacing cards.

The "cash last" model helps us navigate a virtual, electronic world just like we can add items to an ecommerce shopping card without having first created an account replicates the experience of a real world bricks and mortar world of adding items into your cart without having to show a passport at the store's entrance first...:)

I don't believe it's universally adopted through (been to some banks/countries where card is last).

Answer (score 1):

In the UK, we used to give the cash before the card about 20 years ago (IIRC) and I have distinct memories of people being called back to ATM's by the next user because they had forgotten their card as something that happened on more than a few occasions when I was present.

This is because the cash is the thing the user was looking to get, so is the entire purpose of the interaction. Once cash has been received, it is very easy to subconsciously feel that the interaction is over.

Since the switch, I have only ever left cash in the machine once, and that was when I got distracted by a phone call at just the wrong moment. I don't hear of people leaving their cards behind very often these days (and when they do, it's as the result of a scam being run), and I certainly don't hear stories of people leaving money in the machine very often. I don't have any stats to back that up as anything more than annecdotal evidence though.

Comment: Maybe we should have disposable cards, but cash that we hold on to and reuse?