# How could you prevent users from leaving their original copy in the photocopier?

Tags: design, physical

I've done this myself on many occasions, even though I *know* it's a common mistake I need to watch out for.

The steps seem to go as follows *(with typical thoughts in brackets)*:

1. Walk up to photocopier carrying sheet/book to copy.
2. Insert sheet. *("Which way round does this need to go?")*
3. Figure out the controls. *("How does this thing work again?")*
4. Stand for a while as lights flash and cogs whirr. *("Is it working? I hope it's quick.")*
5. Copy comes out. *("Great. At last.")*
6. Grab copied paper and rush out of room, leaving the original in the copier.

Can anyone suggest a way that the photocopier could be designed to prevent users making this mistake?

A sign would seem to be the most obvious way, but the trouble is that the moment I need to read it is likely to be the moment I'm least inclined to stop and read anything.

Comment: Many photocopiers these days come with feed input, rather than flat-bed, and this doesn't suffer from this problem.

Comment: @Brendon But I assume those don't allow for copying thicker documents or books. Although they would prevent sheninigans with the photocopier at the Christmas party :-)

Comment: @Urbycoz - I've never seen any body part involved in Christmas party shenanigans get left on the photocopier. Unless our Christmas party shenanigans are of a different caliber than the norm...

Comment: I have three ideas, all used in conjunction for better efficiency: 1- put the picture of the person on the company website's Hall of Shame 2- whip the person 3- leave a very scary secretary with a British accent deal with the whipping and reminders. Now I'm off to check if I forgot any originals... just in case, bye! More seriously, push the printed copy on top of the original?

Comment: @Kheldar: I think you're misunderstanding the goal here. No one cares if someone leaves the original behind -- except the person who left it behind. The goal here is to *help* that person, by helping them remember. Increasing the penalty for forgetting just aggravates the problem.

Comment: I think the photocopier will be dead in 10 years.  For whatever's not online, take a picture of a page with your phone, software corrects for viewing angle, and print.

Comment: tldr: I've seen some copiers that beep if a document is left on the glass.

Comment: Bit of an out of the box idea, but we just have a sheet of paper on the wall next to the door, right at eye level that says 'don't forget your original copy', never seen anyone forget it in the few years i've been here.

Comment: @RhyW Do people really stop and read the words every time they see it? Besides, what if the photocopier is not in a different room, so there's no door to attach it to?

Comment: The ones that have the feed also allow you to lift the entire thing up like normal, for books.

Comment: @Kheldar hmm, whipping... Could be an incentive for some to actually leave things on the copier...

Comment: @Urbycoz they dont need to read it every time, you sort of see it and it sparks the memory that you need to pick up your copies. If you see something enough times you know what it says without having to read it again. And signs can always be put on posts, or stands, or boards, or walls, or even on the photocopier itself

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is a similar question to [the one about ATMs](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23462/why-dont-atms-give-you-cash-before-your-card), and a similar approach could be adopted.

Since modern machines can detect that there is an original on the glass (or in the ADF), it would suffice to prevent access to the copies until the original is removed.

For that, the completed copies would have to remain inside the machine behind a door which is only unlocked when appropriate to do so.

I used an industrial-size Kodak copier in the mid-Eighties which did this. The finisher where copies ended up (whether actually collated, folded or stapled, or not) was **inside** the main body of the machine. Because it was a *very* fast machine which moved paper with compressed air and vacuums, all paper movement was internal and doors were only unlocked when it was safe to do so.

The only thing which would be needed is a lit indication near the output door handle (as well as on the main display) to explain why it's locked shut.

[image]

Comment: I've got 20 sheets to copy, but I want to check the first one has printed ok before continuing with the rest. Do I have to take out the original before I can see the newly printed one?

Comment: No, because modern copiers come with a "Preview" button which can deliver a single copy outside the machine. Using that for a single copy would run the risk of leaving the original behind, though. I'll continue to think...

Comment: Most copiers now are basically scanners and printers. The don't actually use the xerox process any more. So scanning 20 sheets to disc, getting you to take the originals away and then printing all 20 sheets isn't a problem. (The fact copiers do this is a security issue - their hard drives need to be treated as having sensitive info on them!)

Comment: @PeterBagnall Yes. See my other idea.

Comment: They have CPUs, ethernet/wifi, and hard disks/flash. Printers, a hacker paradise.

Comment: @PeteBagnall -- the xerographic process is how the toner is deposited onto the paper. All laser printers use the xerographic process. The transfer surface can be excited by light reflected off of the original or from a laser. It's xerographic either way.

Comment: I do like this answer quite a bit, but... One thing that bugs me is the use of the word "platen" in the graphic.  Does the average user have the slightest idea what a "platen" is?  I would guess that they do not.  I would suggest using a different, common English word instead of the more technical "platen".

Comment: This is a proper technique to eliminate human 'postcompletion errors' for the task: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?q=postcompletion+error&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C44

Comment: It's not entirely necessary to detect that there's a sheet of paper on the glass. After the document has been scanned, assume the original is still there until the cover is lifted. I'm not likely to scan my document, then lift the cover, and *still* leave the original on the glass.

Comment: @MikeS "Original still present. Remove original copy."

Comment: @AndrewLeach. "Original copy" sounds a bit strange to me. Maybe just "Original still present. Please remove".

Comment: I read the last three lines of this answer and thought the doors of the *room* were locked until the user removed their original. That would be effective, but a bit risky... what if the sensor malfunctioned? http://www.nytimes.com/2012/05/03/us/daniel-chong-left-for-days-in-holding-cell.html

Comment: @LarsH Newspaper Headline: "Employee burned to death, while locked in photocopier room. 'They must have forgotten to remove the original' claims colleague."

Comment: @Urbycoz: Fatal Prank: Disgruntled Employee Leaves Glue on Copier Platen. (Details at 11:00.)

Answer (score 25):

In addition to [my other method](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/42993/12718), a cheaper indication would be to have the copier beep when it's finished until the original is removed from the platen. Accompany the beep with a display message and warning light indicating the cause of the "error"<sup>1</sup>.

This would also allow the original to be removed after scanning, while printing is happening (there would be no need for the beep). A refinement would be needed to cope with removing the current original and replacing it with the next; that shouldn't cause the beep either unless it looks as though nothing is going to be done with it.

<sup>1</sup> It's not an error, of course, so its code should *not* start with E for Error, and it should have a yellow indicator light, not a red one.

Comment: I could see this being very disruptive in a shared office environment

Comment: I was going to write something similar, but I would start the beeping not until the copies are lifted. This will train people to take their original first and then the copies. So they'll get into that habit even if there are some old copiers, which don't have an alarm.

Comment: @Chris Is it going to be reliable enough to correctly detect when copies have and have not been lifted? Tesco always seems to struggle- "Unexpected item in the bagging area".

Comment: Our copier does exactly this.  If you do not pick up the original when the copies have been completed it makes a beeping sound and displays a message to remind you.  It works well.  I have never left an original behind.

Comment: @KennyPeanuts Glad you told me. I was about to apply for the patent.

Comment: @Chris, Urbycoz I'm offended you guys are talking about how offended you are at each other.

Comment: Beeping is also what ATMs use in Singapore to remind you to take your card after taking your cash.

Answer (score 22):

Design the copier so that the original is deposited with the copy.

The user will already need to pick up the copy **to leave** or **to verify that the copy is satisfactory**.

#### Updated below for books & bulky original

**Alternatively** - a conveyor mechanism that gently deposits the book/or push it out the end where you would look to pick up your copies. You can add a timer on the copier cover so that this can be triggered if the cover has not been lifted within 2 seconds. That way it covers the scenario where the user needs to scan the next pages.

I'd also investigate the ROI on supporting books/bulky originals, because I'm not convinced there'd be too many people who'd forget their originals in these cases.

**Lastly** - I'd investigate the user's work load, as some studies have shown that 'conveniently' forgetting something in the copy room is a subconscious effort to delay work. That can be covered in a different question

Comment: What if the original is a book, rather than a sheet?

Comment: Excellent query. We made an assumption that the original was a sheet of paper.

Comment: Would the variations in the form factor of the original impact the scope of your question?

Comment: The idea still applies. You put the book in, start scanning, then you have to open the scanning unit to get to your copies.

Comment: @Urbycoz I'm thinking of little elves that magically appear and move your book to the tray where the copies are deposited.

Comment: I'm submitting a patent for "iElves"

Comment: @micap I hope the elves aren't too rough. I'm planning to photocopy some valuable antique books.

Comment: @Urbycoz - done. I'll leave the elves out for now

Comment: @micap I agree that people are less likely to forget their book than their original sheet. However that is surely irrelevant since we must somehow cater for both groups of people. And if we provide any system for book users, it will also get used by sheet users.

Comment: I don't see a real problem with the book. The problem appears to be that the output is delivered too far away from the input source, moving the focus of attention. You'd be much better off moving the **output** (which has to move anyway) near the input. E.g. underneath the input, in the space where the line scanner moved, and reachable only by lifting the lid.

Comment: I wonder how in the world "studies have shown" "a subconscious effort." Can subconscious things be counted?

Comment: @MSalters Now *that* is a good idea.  Move the thing that you know is easy to move (output paper)!

Comment: @LarsH lol, no one said anything about counting.  Research into memory and motivated forgetting is quite interesting, and it usually concerns both conscious and subconscious behaviour.

Comment: No doubt the research is interesting, but I'm still wondering how studies can "show" subconscious effort.

Answer (score 10):

Instead of a copy machine that spits out copies from the side of the machine, redesign it to spit copies out to the same spot where your original is.  That way, you will always grab everything you need in one place before you jet off!

Comment: Install echolocation in the printer to determine the location of the human operator. When a human moves more than 6 ft away from the printer have a gruff voice soundeffect play: STOP! your papers have been abandoned! Open the photocopier for more details. Or place the photocopier in a closet with saloon style doors that lock and display the previous message when the paper is still in the photocopier.

Comment: @user4380 Could it first detect whether the user has a weak heart before shouting at him?

Answer (score 8):

@Andrew is spot on to say that the ATM design is the right way to think about this - you get your money last, since that makes sure you don't forget to take your card.

So I'd separate the scanning part of the process from the printing part. So first off you put your original on the scan bed, press a scan button to scan, remove, add the next sheet and so on until you're done. Printing would only start once you're done scanning. This might seem like it would slow you down, but you're not going to copy a 400 page doc page by page without a sheet feeder anyhow, so it's not really a big problem. A sheet feeder should pass the original next to where the copies come out so you naturally pick up both at the same time.

For single page copying if you scan, but haven't opened the lid to remove your original then the copier knows that there's something still on the bed. So it can refuse to print until you remove it, with a suitable message to say why it's not printing of course.

Once you've done all your scanning and removed your last copy you hit the print button and your copies come out. Having a prominent display of how many pages you've scanned or a timeout would be useful to prevent accidents (or pranks) like people scanning something, but not printing so that the next user gets more than they were expecting.

Comment: +1 for the answer I would have written. You said "you get your money last, since that makes sure you don't forget to take your card", Don Norman calls this a "forcing function" which I mention because it is good to have a name to hang concepts on. The reason it works so well with the ATM is that you went there to get cash and you aren't likely to leave until that purpose is satisfied. Contrariwise, you **did not** go to the ATM with the intention of inserting your card, so it is easy to leave without it.

Answer (score 5):

Place the output in a collection bin which is accessible from the front, but only when the top cover is lifted. Lifting it will give access to the output, but also uncover the input, refocusing attention. The problem with the current design is the physical separation of input and output, which moves the focus of attention too far away from the input.

Comment: I like this solution. Simple and low-tech but effective.

Comment: The idea is based on the "forcing function" you mentioned in another comment. Lifting the cover is already an established action for retrieving your input, but this makes it _also_ a forcing function for output. Thoughtwise "I need my output -> I need to lift cover -> there's both my in- and output"

Answer (score 4):

Have the cover of the copier pop up and maybe chime when the copies are done, leaving the original exposed and grab-able.

Comment: Ow! I was standing too close to the cover, and now I've got to visit the dentist.

Answer (score 3):

Set up the copier so the glass faces down or vertical and the user has to hold the original in place.

**EDIT**:

The Stack Exchange bots are asking for a longer answer with more context. So here it goes: With a vertical glass, it would be impossible for the user to walk away without their original since it would fall to the ground when they left.

There are obvious downsides.

- Photocopying heavy books and magazines would be awkward
- People with disablities might have trouble holding the original in this way
- It might be hard to keep the original aligned correctly
- With a traditional photocopier you'd always be staring into the bright light of the copier

The easiest solution would be to ensure that the capture of the original was as close to instantaneous as possible so that the time required to hold the original against the glass was limited. Software would also be designed to auto-rotate the copies in perfect 90 degree increments. Finally, the hardware could sense where the original is located (perhaps using touch-sensitive glass) so that the scanner light would only shine where the original is placed against the glass.

Obviously this isn't a solution for every use case where a copier is used, but it does solve the original question.

Comment: It would cause many issues, but I like the lateral thinking.

Comment: I'm trying to copy a page from the encyclopedia Britannica. I've wasted 50 sheets trying to get one that wasn't blurred due to my shaking arms. And now my arms feel like they're going to drop off.

Comment: @Urbycoz: First, you use the other copier to take a photocopy of that page from the encyclopedia. Then you hold the photocopy up to the vertical glass to make your real copy.

Comment: @LarsH Two copies for the price of one. Sorted! (And it only required having two copiers.)

Comment: I like simple physical constraints too. This is sort of like making diesel nozzles wider than unleaded ones to prevent you from filling up your gas-powered car with diesel fuel.

Answer (score 3):

For minimal modification to present photocopiers, you could have a **sign always placed on top of the stack of output copies**.  This would be the most suitable place for a sign that reads **"Please remove your original."** as it would be *directly in the path of the only action you **know** the user is going to take*.

The sign could be attached to the machine, and be made to automatically retract once the original cover is opened.

This solution could actually be *retro-fitted to existing copiers with minimal modification using just a firmware change*, if it were worth using a bit of extra paper and toner (this might be arguable for a public library, say, where forgetting an original could be a big inconvenience (people remembering it after they have left!)):  The photocopier could simply be made to add a page matching the sign description above to the end of every copy job.

Comment: Or just set the machine to print an enforced title page with the sign on it. Wasteful, sure - but simple to do on existing machines in this case.

Comment: That is Part 2 of my answer, but yes.  ;)

Answer (score 3):

The major factor in forgetting the copy is because users cannot see their original when the lid is closed. There is an innovative solution to this: make the lid transparent. The user can see their original in the photocopier before, during and after scanning. This makes it significantly less likely that the user will forget to take the original.

From above, it would look something like this:

[image: Transparent lid photocopier]

The sliding back drop moves between two panes of glass, in tandem with the photocopier element.

Comment: Probably easier and more reliable to use an LCD instead of a mechanical solution, but expensive either way.

Answer (score 1):

A couple options:

- Cheap method: **Stick a paper** saying "Don't forget to collect the original documents!" on the base of the collection tray. Good chance user will see that when collecting the copies.
- Modify displays: Most photocopiers/printers have a digital display on them for various purposes. Rather than just saying "Job done", you can **tweak the message to say "Collect the documents and the copies"** or something to first remind the user to collect the originals.
- Modify hardware: You can have a **backlight or something under the closing lid** go on/pulsate (for a while) when the job is completed to draw the user's attention to the lid (and hence the original document). It should be a good enough affordance to make the user take some action. You can make this smarter by doing it only if the lid is not opened following the completion of a job (a few seconds' delay).

Answer (score 1):

What about a photoelectric cell (or a weight, but with paper that's rather tricky) that detects if the original document is still on the scanner before releasing the copies?

One of the most effective methods for *"not forgetting what you didn't come for"* is the ATM's *"get your card so we can give you your money"* method.

Answer (score 0):

An MP3 player triggered to play "Please don't forget your original. Have a nice day!"

Comment: That wouldn't ever get annoying.

Comment: Just change it to "Never gonna give you up!" and you're good.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting problem. I think the mental model is that I input in one place and take the output from another place.. so the focus is more on the place the paper is coming out from.

Photocopiers can just scan once and print any number of copies, so after the first scan, the copiers should just send the original out to a tray next to where copies are.

Ofcourse this cannot be done with thicker objects like a book etc.. but they are probably less likely to be forgotten also, as they change the visual of the input space, making it more visible.